# google map location not present in user view

Tags: javascript, google-maps

There is google map present in my web site. I loaded this in to pop up window.
but when i load this the location is not present in centre. I need to scroll the 
map. If any thing wrong about this. If any one know about this. please help me.
i am new to this.

```
  <div class="modal-header">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;      </button>
  <h4 class="modal-title" id="map-title">Australia</h4>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-body" style="padding-right: 0;padding-left: 25px;">
   <iframe width="96%" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0"   marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.co.in/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=32+Martin+Place,+Sydney,+New+South+Wales,+Australia&amp;aq=0&amp;oq=32+Martin+Place&amp;sll=-33.872954,151.205488&amp;sspn=0.005336,0.009645&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=32+Martin+Pl,+Sydney+New+South+Wales+2000,+Australia&amp;ll=-33.867659,151.209329&amp;spn=0.005336,0.009645&amp;t=m&amp;z=14&amp;output=embed"></iframe><br /><small><a href="https://maps.google.co.in/maps?f=q&amp;source=embed&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=32+Martin+Place,+Sydney,+New+South+Wales,+Australia&amp;aq=0&amp;oq=32+Martin+Place&amp;sll=-33.872954,151.205488&amp;sspn=0.005336,0.009645&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=32+Martin+Pl,+Sydney+New+South+Wales+2000,+Australia&amp;ll=-33.867659,151.209329&amp;spn=0.005336,0.009645&amp;t=m&amp;z=14" style="color:#0000FF;text-align:left">View Larger Map</a></small>
  </div>
```

Comment: Sounds like you load the map first and then the iframe gets smaller for some reason?

Comment: yes, but i can;t manage the zomming

Comment: Maybe set the iframe source when you open the modal?